# Configure build path suggestion when trying to extend ActionBarActivity

Tags: android

I’m trying to extend my class from ActionBarActivity and cant, already tried every possible way I know. I’m importing android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; I want to add the lib without the resource as instructed on the android developer’s site. And every time I get the same error....I upload some photos

this is the error: Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider. Fix the build path then try building this project   xxx     Unknown Java Problem

[a busy cat http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/1032/qlei.jpg](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/1032/qlei.jpg)
[a busy cat http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/6339/n4cj.jpg](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/6339/n4cj.jpg)

thanks

Comment: You have to import the resources along with the code - they are all part of the library and all required.

Answer (score 3):

The problem has been fixed for me after adding android support library.

> Right Click -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have the android-support v7-appcompat project in the Projects tab on Java Build Path as in the picture:

(I can't add the picture to you, but you find it by right clicking your project and choose Build Path --> Configure Build Path)

Check also that that project does not report any error.

I am a novice but I just passed by the same obstacle a couple of minutes ago.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the whole project and it started working.....strange